# Cryptic Family Reunion: Any Title I Can Think Of Would Give Away The Theme To Somebody

Tags: cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". **NOTE:** Unlike many previous puzzles in this genre, clues are NOT sorted alphabetically; however, lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Pappy heard wise-cracking about a desert migration (9)
2. Sister's affair about at an end, sadly (6)
3. Son's music intro takes a second (6)
4. Daughter, tearing down barriers, gets in shape (4)
5. Irrational $2,000 investment elicited stock tips from uncle (7)
6. Niece cut down date introduced by Caesar (5)
7. Dick, Barb walk around lake with Dad (9)
8. Granddad whoops the hide off young 'uns (4)
9. Grandma's riding chopper at back? (6)
10. Brother's special sauce between two layers of beef (7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are

> song titles by The Beatles.

Pappy heard wise-cracking about a desert migration (9)

> Y(ESTERDA*)Y - "Y's" sounds like "wise"

Sister's affair about at an end, sadly (6)

> FL(_Y)ING

Son's music intro takes a second (6)

> CH(A)IN+S, apparently referring to "chin music" (see comments)

Daughter, tearing down barriers, gets in shape (4)

> (-t)RAIN(-s)

Irrational $2,000 investment elicited stock tips from uncle (7)

> PI+GG+I_+E_+S_

Niece cut down date introduced by Caesar (5)

> JULIA(-n)

Dick, Barb walk around lake with Dad (9)

> B(L)ACKBIRD*

Granddad whoops the hide off young 'uns (4)

> (-w)HELP(-s)

Grandma's riding chopper at back? (6)

> _T+AXMAN

Brother's special sauce between two layers of beef (7)

> B(ECAUS*)E_

Comment: Nailed it! But I figured this one would go a lot quicker. For #3, rot13(puva zhfvp vf na vqvbz sbe vqyr gnyx, znlor gbb Nzrevpna?)